# Full button title not showing when i change the title from code (iPad)

Tags: ipad, button, title

I am trying to change my ipad apps button title programatically using the following code:

```
btnCompany.titleLabel.text = @"Groenhuysen";
```

But when I run the code I can see the title is: Groen..en

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[btnCompany setTitle:@"Groenhuysen" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yes, it works for me. I have used this code yesterday.